# Using copied pictures for website

Tags: metadata

I have take some before and after pictures for my business. After posting them on social media sites, I generally lose track of the originals that usually are around 4-5mb in size.

If I want to use the picture again on another site, I am generally forced to download it from the social media site and then post the copied picture somewhere else. However, the field size many times is 100-200kb. For just viewing on a computer will this matter in terms of quality pictures? (This shot is 115kb)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a size that works for on-screen viewing, though it could be good to have higher-res versions. I wouldn't go too high-quality for images in a Website, anyway. You want your site to load quickly and be good for mobile users. So, I don't see it as a big issue that you have lost track of your original files. But it would be better, in future, to keep your best portfolio shots in a place where you won't lose them. Maybe get a free Dropbox account and store those files in your Dropbox directory on your computer and let them be duplicated to "the cloud", where they'll be handy for you, whenever you need them for a brochure or new use. You should try to track down your originals, but at least the size you've shared here is okay for a Website.

Comment: No problem. Not to quibble, but I really would want the originals if I were you. l hadn't noticed the photo was only one file. In a website, you might want to show the "before" photo, only if the portfolio link to the "After" is clicked. You might also want to place the text (Before / After) with HTML / CSS, rather than rasterizing & embedding it in your photo. And, in a side-by-side comparison (or above/below), you may want to show the "Before" above (or to the left of) the "After", as is normally "standard practice". The low-quality JPEGs would be a bad "starting point" for any new files.

Comment: This is a case in point for my question about version tracking.  https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88354/how-do-you-maintain-metadata-across-multiple-images?noredirect=1#comment179705_88354

Comment: Actually, I think it more points to why to keep copies of all your best original images (ideally, as raw images) and why to work non-destructively, as much as possible.